# Does order of <location> in web.config matters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I have set a FormAuthentication to my website.

I want to allow annonymous access to the Login page and its resources (js, css, images).

I have added  to web.config. Does the order there matter?

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration"  
             type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
    <section name="log4net" 
             type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="~/Authentication.htm">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/Resources">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/js">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/Images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/Controllers">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        .....
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="Login" loginUrl="~/Authentication.htm"
             protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
       <deny users ="?" />
       <allow users = "*" />
    </authorization>
```

Why do I still get authentication errors for the path I have added to the ?

```
Authentication.htm?ReturnUrl=%2fResources%2fScripts%2fjquery-1.7.1.min.js:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Authentication.htm?ReturnUrl=%2fjs%2fCommon.js:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Authentication.htm?ReturnUrl=%2fjs%2fAuthentication.js:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root setting denies all unauthenticated users (`?`) and your location settings deny all users (`*`).

You probably meant to do this:

```
<!-- web application root settings -->
<authorization>
   <deny users ="?" />
</authorization>

<!-- login and static resources -->
<location path="~/Images">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: It didn't help. I want to allow non-authorized user to get all relevant content on the login page (js, css, images). After writing your config, I still don't get the Imgaes and the scripts.

Comment: I've seen that before when running from Visual Studio, but it would still work when deployed to IIS.

Comment: The problem was the `~`. I thought it was more clear with that, but it failed the relative path

Answer (score 0):

Order does matter in that if you have duplicate elements, only the last element will be taken into consideration.